# Where is Sanji in this currently ongoing Dressrosa fight?

Tags: one-piece

Sanji appeared in the starting of the Dressrosa arc and fought with Doflamingo for a short span.

However, I haven't seen him in any of the ongoing Dressrosa fights (I mean he should have been there to defeat the executives or family of Doflamingo).

Or have I missed something in between?

Comment: I don't remember where they went but Sanji and others went ahead somewhere before dressora fight

Comment: Sanji is probably having some tea with Big Mom in Zou, since her daughter is indebted to the straw hats after Triller Bark

Comment: what?? daugther indebted to the straw hats?? can you give link manga link supporting to this ?

Comment: [In chapter 489](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GeG36.jpg) it was inclined that Lola was referring to Big Mom. The fact that Lola came from the new world, with her *mama* being an awesome pirate there, most people believe she was referring to Big Mom herself.

Comment: ohh don't remember this chapter..but yeah there are doubts about lola's mom... lets wait for few more chapters.. thanks @PeterRaeves

Comment: Also the fact that Lola calls nami "Nami**Zou**" might be a reference that she came from Zou.

Comment: @PeterRaeves Didn't she call her NamiZOU because she thought Nami was a guy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now **Sanji** is amidst the fight with the Big Mom Pirates along with Nami, Chopper, Brook, and Kinemon's son Momonosuke. Then they were heading to where the Trafalgar's nakama were supposed to meet at **Zou**. Big Mom's pirates were after Caesar which was alsp with them. He was requested by **Franky** not to allow those Big Mom Pirates close to Dressrosa or else the Tontattas' efforts will be wasted (it doesn't seems to be logical enough to me though) and Sanji was granted the permission to annihilate Big Mom Pirates as Luffy has already challenged her. Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVicPkzh_ys) showing Sanji group leaving for Zou.

I guess in the background the fight is still going on.

**Edits and Updates:**
This answer has heavy spoilers. Otakus who don't read manga are advised not to read the spoiler...

> The manga has completed the Dressrosa arc! And then in Chapter 795, it appears that Sanji and his team has left the Big Mom Pirates, as shown: [image: Chapter 795: Page 4]  And from the background of the manga it appears **they have already reached Zou.** They escaped from Big Mom Pirates maybe because they (Big Mom Pirates) would’ve proved too much for Sanji and others. (It's an assumption. Nothing is specified canonically).
>
>  Then in Chapter 801 the raise in the Bounty of the Straw Hat crew specified that **Sanji was wanted alive!**: [image]  which may imply Sanji is an important personnel that the government needs!
>
>  Now the latest Chapter 806 says Sanji is not present at Zou but in some trouble! Here: [image]  Since Oda-Sensei is known for his cliff-hangers, this last page determines that Sanji was somehow overpowered and taken **ALIVE.** The [Jack Pirate](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Jack) is strongly suspected to have taken Sanji! He might have taken Sanji for some personal gains from the Marines or to become a Shichibukai (like how [Trafalgar Law did](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Trafalgar_D._Water_Law#Personality) as mentioned in 6th line of 7th paragraph) since Doflamingo is no more a Shichibukai and a seat is vacant! These are just my **HYPOTHESIS** and where Sanji might currently be can only be declared by Oda-Sensei in the next few upcoming chapters!

Comment: Well your answer seems convincing

Comment: Currently in the manga the strawhats and samurai have reached zou but have yet to actually meet up with them. Though there are several allusions that sanji is already on zou after they split up in Dressrosa. However, the battle with big mom and how that turned out is still a mystery until Oda puts out more cannon

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **SANJI** was beaten by jack's men or some sort of strong guys and bring him to marijois since there's a rumor that sanji is a son of one of those gorosei. wanted list says sanji should be taken only alive and in chapter 806  think nami's tears and sorry is meant for sanji's loss.

Comment: Just read chapter 806, Yeah the last part Nami saying sorry does create some suspense but I have a doubt Sanji got beaten by Jack's Men